# Cannot convert the expression's type '()' 'NilLiteralConverible'?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

the following code build error:

```
var err:NSError?
_persistentStore = _persistentStoreCoordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(
            NSSQLiteStoreType,
            configuration: nil,
            URL: _coreDataPathURL,
            options: nil,
            error: err
    )
```

build error:Cannot convert the expression's type '()' 'NilLiteralConverible' ?

_persistentStoreCoordinator is a optional var.

I don't understand why build error?!

Comment: You're missing an `&` before you pass in the `error` as a parameter.

Comment: Note that (as of now) the error messages clang provides are not really helpful in most of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the error type needs to be an `NSErrorPointer`, i.e. a pointer to an `NSError?`.

To implicitly convert an `NSError?` to one of those, you can just stick a `&` in front of `err`:

```
var err:NSError?
_persistentStore = _persistentStoreCoordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(
            NSSQLiteStoreType,
            configuration: nil,
            URL: _coreDataPathURL,
            options: nil,
            error: &err // <--
    )
```

(see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_7) for more info)

The build error is because Swift is attempting to use `NSError`’s `NilLiteralConvertible` initializer, but failing because that needs a type of `()` as its argument (beware, when Swift can’t make any of the possible overloads work, it often gives you a compiler error about one specific possibility, which can be misleading).

Comment: After I posted this question, I also found that .

Comment: Swift and Xcode error reporting is so bad I swear. I had the same problem and Xcode was underlining "configuration: nil" part as being wrong, saying something like "Cannot convert the expression's type '$T13??' to type 'NilLiteralConvertible'" -_-!